# Validate User Input, check if input is an integer and within range

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, try-catch

**Thanks Adi219 & Charles Spencer for helping with my part 1.

Now i'm trying a different approach, by validating the input before it store into an array, it look fine most of the time, but the exception only run once.

This is what i input to test the validating

1) I input "a", it returned "enter number between 0 to 100" which is correct.

2) I input 1000, and it returned "Invalid age" which i can tell that my IF conditions works.

3) No issue when i input the correct value for User no.1

Problem happens when i try to run the same test on User no.2. After I input correct value for User no.1, I type in "A" again and the programs just bypass all those conditions and captured no integer value.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test2
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
int i = 0;             
double x = 0;
double Total = 0;            
double Average = 0; 
int Users = 2; //I fixed a number for testing purpose
boolean isNumber =false;
double ages[] = new double[Users];     
 
    for(int counter =0; counter < Users; counter++){ 
    System.out.print("Enter the age for users "+(counter+1)+ ": ");
     do{
            try {
  x =input.nextDouble();
  if(x<0 || x>100){
                    System.out.print("Invalid age.. try again.. ");
                    }else if(x>0 || x<100){isNumber=true;}
     }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.print("Please enter number between 0 to 100 ");
     input.next();
    }
 }while(!(isNumber));
 System.out.println("User Age is "+ x); //Just to check input user's age
 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. Variable names start lowercase. And consider leaving out the salutation parts in your questions. Use comments to say thank you. Questions should be about technical content only.

Comment: And then read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. I have no clue what you expecting and what exactly happens. Don't just throw up some code - give us a clear and complete [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

Because your entire do/while loop is based on whether isNumber is false, if you enter a valid number for user1, the isNumber variable is set to true, and the do/while loop will never run again because you never set isNumber back to false. There are two places were I set isNumber back to false, I've marked them. But I'm pretty sure this whole thing should be rewritten. For example there's no need to do:

```
else if(x > 0 || x < 100)
```

because you've already done:

```
if(x<0 || x>100)
```

If you do the first condition as x <= 0 || x >= 100 there's no need to do an else if statement.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < Users; counter++)
    {   
    System.out.print("Enter the age for users "+(counter+1)+ ": ");
        do{
            try {
                x = input.nextDouble();

                if(x<0 || x>100)
                {
                    isNumber = false; // Set to false if invalid number
                    System.out.print("Invalid age.. try again.. ");
                }
                else if(x > 0 || x < 100) 
                      {isNumber = true;} // If the age for user1 is valid, isNumber is set 
                                         // to true
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                isNumber = false; // Set to false if number invalid
                System.out.print("Please enter number between 0 to 100 ");
                input.next();
                }
    }while(!(isNumber));
```

Comment: Thanks Zebrafish, it's good to take a nap before re-read the code again.